# Sign document with out using encryption an encryption?

Tags: security, authentication, hash

Is this possible to sign document with out using an encryption??
if possible then how ??

Normally we sign document using encrypting user private key with the message and send to other user and other user decrypt this message using sender public key.
but it is this possible without encryption process any other process?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here, but in general, there is no need to use encryption to sign messages. It is true, in a sense, that certain algorithms like RSA can be used for both public-key encryption and digital signatures, and that the RSA signature operation can (loosely speaking) be described as ["encrypting with the private key"](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2123). This does not, however, [hold for most other digital signature algorithms like DSA.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2585)

Comment: In any case, your question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. It could be on topic for [crypto.SE] Stack Exchange, but you'd probably be better off taking a look at some of the [earlier related questions](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption+signature) there first.

Comment: Your understanding of signing is not correct, hence your question (which is not correct either). Digital signing is not encryption and doesn't involve encryption as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of hash based message authentication code's (HMAC), or even just hash codes.

For example, you can just hash the document and verify the hash to ensure no tampering occurred.  Problem here is managing that hash value, because let's say you pass that hash with the document.  Somebody could edit the document, update the hash, and you would be none the wiser.

A keyed hash solves all those problems, but you must properly manage that secret key.